# Remove React components that throw an error from a grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that displays a grid of tiles. Some of those tiles might throw an error when they try to render. Using an error boundary I could simply capture the error and return a different component (e.g., one showing an error message).

But, what I would really like is to make the tiles that throw an error disappear and not to take space in the grid (that is, no empty space should exist between tiles because of a tile that threw an error).

I thought I had a solution, but it turns out it is not working. The idea was to store the tiles in state, and then make the error boundary execute a callback function that would remove the problematic tiles from the state. But, it seems the method that captures the error in the error boundary does not have access to React state.

Following you can see the code for this idea:

```js
const Tile = (props: { id: string }) => {
  if (parseInt(props.id) % 2 === 0) {
    throw new Error("error");
  }

  return <div>It worked!</div>;
};

const SafeTile = (props: { id: string; onError: (id: string) => void }) => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary
      fallback={<div>Error!</div>}
      onError={() => props.onError(props.id)}
    >
      <Tile id={props.id} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [tiles, setTiles] = useState<{ [key: string]: JSX.Element }>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const removeTile = (id: string) => {
      const tilesCopy = {...tiles};
      delete tilesCopy[id];
      setTiles(tilesCopy);
    };

    setTiles({
      "1": <SafeTile id="1" onError={removeTile} />,
      "2": <SafeTile id="2" onError={removeTile} />,
      "3": <SafeTile id="3" onError={removeTile} />
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(tiles).map(([id, tile]) => (
        <div key={id}>{tile}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can find a sandbox for this code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-albattani-iupii

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? Am I just doing it the wrong way?

**UPDATE**

To make the desired solution more clear, I will show the expected DOM elements in the grid. Assuming a single row with three tiles, and the second tile throwing an error, I expect to have the following elements:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" key="1">
    <SafeTile ...>...</SafeTile>
  </div>
  <div class="column" key="3">
    <SafeTile ...>...</SafeTile>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to aseferov's answer, I found out I was not updating the state correctly. Simply changing the function `removeTile` to the following made the approach work.

```js
    const removeTile = (id: string) => {
      setTiles(_tiles => {
        const tilesCopy = {..._tiles};
        delete tilesCopy[id];
        return tilesCopy;
      });
    };
```

Comment: I would personally just pass the error handler function to the Tile components and wrap the risky function that throws an error inside a try/catch. In the catch you call the passed error handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put grid div inside SafeTile it will be removed on error

```
const App = (): JSX.Element => {

  const [tiles, setTiles] = useState<number[]>([1,2,3]);


  return (
    <div>
      {tiles.map((id) => (
        <SafeTile key={id} id={id} onError={() => {
          setTiles(_tiles => _tiles.filter(t => t !== id))
        }}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


const SafeTile = (props: { id: string; onError: () => void }) => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary
      fallback={<></>}
      onError={props.onError}
    >
      <div>
        <Tile id={props.id} />
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

Comment: But this won't go the column go away -- it will simply leave the cell empty (with the fragment), right? I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case. first you make an array with all the cells you will render, and then you cut them by number of columns

Comment: @Promet99 I gave that a try earlier but the tile components are not "rendered" yet when they are in the array. So, it does not seem to be possible to know whether the error will be thrown once the components (cells) are rendered -- and therefore filter them out in advance.

Comment: its not just fragment you also need to put `<div class="column"` in SafeTile

Comment: @betabandido It seems like tiles are filtered by there props.id. Parent component can access props.id of its child. So the data could be filtered inside the parent component, and the filtered data will be used to make tiles

Comment: @aseferov Indeed, using fragment and moving the column into `SafeTile` works. But, I don't see a way for this approach to work once I have let's say two rows, and there is an error in a tile in the first row that forces a tile from the second row to move into the first one.

Comment: @betabandido in this case you need to remove tiles from state when error happened, updated my answer

Comment: @aseferov That worked! The problem was I was trying to read the state while updating it too instead of using a callback with `setState` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good idea, but I personally think this may not be a 'Reactish' structure at all, since the child component is effecting parent components.

More Reactish structure (which would decrease the possibility of error and workarounds like this case) would let the parent component first decide which child component should be rendered, and then render whichever is deemed adequate.

Comment: I have the same feeling too. I considered running some "validations" somewhere up the component tree that determine which tiles need to be shown. But, that does not seem to solve the case where a tile throws an error. I suppose the likelihood of an error goes down because of the validation, but I was hoping for a solution that always works, even in the presence of errors.